# How to connect strophe without password

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

Currently, I can able to connect with strophe by giving jid and password in Angular project. But by giving jid and password is not safe. Instead of giving jid and password, is there any other way like JWT simple authentication? Ejabberd is hosted in local system with Windows OS.

I am looking for token based login.

```
this._xmppConnection = new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:5280/bosh/", { 'keepalive': true });

this._xmppConnection.connect(jid, password, this._onConnect);
// working one
```

I am looking for connecting strophe using JWT token. Is there such support in ejabberd?

Comment: I am also looking for the same

Answer (score 4):

@sahal You can achieve that using other mediums of authentication eg. OAuth token

Generate OAuth token for user using ejabberd api.

- endpoint: /api/oauth_issue_token
- sample: curl -H "X-Admin: true" -X POST -u admin_jid:pass -d '{"jid": "user_jid", "ttl": 3600, "scopes": "connected_users_number;sasl_auth"}' http://ip:port/api/oauth_issue_token

While creating strophe instance pass option mechanisms as [Strophe.SASLXOAuth2]

While connecting replace password with your oauth token eg. connection.connect(jid, ejabberd_oauth_token)

Comment: Now i am using openfire , could you please help in the same ?